# "Inconsistent hash" without rejected blocks

Tags: node, archive-node

I repetitively get this error with a mainnet-archive node trying to resync after a crash:

```
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error:
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Inconsistent hash:
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     got: CoUxrgRQq3TtnHGfHFZGNg3sUQdXoZiSsLPxRar5M2nii4ucfSWL
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:     expected: CoVJgM2Q483JKyWkmSbj19s73xjhkgfGSD3LtKaoJGYLaPzbSmfe
Jan 14 17:34:08 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: 
Jan 14 17:34:08 - validator.peer: Worker crashed [validator-peer_81]:
Jan 14 17:34:08 - validator.peer: Inconsistent hash:
Jan 14 17:34:08 - validator.peer:   got: CoUxrgRQq3TtnHGfHFZGNg3sUQdXoZiSsLPxRar5M2nii4ucfSWL
Jan 14 17:34:08 - validator.peer:   expected: CoVJgM2Q483JKyWkmSbj19s73xjhkgfGSD3LtKaoJGYLaPzbSmfe
```

But

```
 $ tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks
No invalid blocks.
```

(
  Had the error with the docker image, so switched to `master` --multinetwork-node-- and same error happens, node had been working fine for a week or so.

Bootstrapped is stuck at

```
Current head: BKr36FzwS185 (timestamp: 2020-01-11T10:18:32-00:00, validation: 2020-01-14T22:41:57-00:00)
```

)